# sql query optimize for IMDB dataset

Tags: mysql, sql

Please help me to optimize following SQL query using sub query:

```
 SELECT TRIM(MC.PID) ACTOR_PID      ,TRIM(MD.PID) DIRECTOR_PID,
 COUNT(DISTINCT TRIM(MD.MID)) AS           NUM_OF_MOV_1

 FROM M_Cast MC,M_Director MD
 WHERE TRIM(MC.MID)= TRIM(MD.MID)
 GROUP BY ACTOR_PID,DIRECTOR_PID
```

Currently it is taking more than 2 minutes to execute. With the help of a subquery I have to make it below 1m.

Comment: [Edit] the question and include a [example]. I.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables and the `CREATE` statements of any indexes on them, `INSERT` statements with sample data, the expected result with that sample data as tabular text and the explain plan of the query.

Comment: (1) Use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.  (2) Do not use functions like `TRIM()` on `JOIN` conditions.  They should not be necessary in a properly defined database.

Comment: @GordonLinoff could you pls help me code, so that i can learn the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should be using explicit join. No that it makes much of a difference for performance but that's just a good habit to get into:

```
SELECT TRIM(MC.PID)                    ACTOR_PID,
       TRIM(MD.PID)                    DIRECTOR_PID,
       COUNT(DISTINCT TRIM(MD.MID)) AS NUM_OF_MOV_1
FROM M_Cast MC join 
     M_Director MD on (TRIM(MC.MID) = TRIM(MD.MID))
GROUP BY ACTOR_PID, DIRECTOR_PID
```

Second thing is that you should store the data so that you don't need to use `TRIM()` as part of the JOIN. To do that first fix the old data:

```
UPDATE M_Cast SET MID=TRIM(MID);
UPDATE M_Director SET MID=TRIM(MID);
```

and then ensure all future inserts are already trimmed. After that you should add the relevant indexes.

```
ALTER TABLE M_Cast ADD INDEX (MID);
ALTER TABLE M_Director ADD INDEX (MID);
```

That should improve your query a lot.

For future reference consider using [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html) to see which keys are being used. For further improvements you need to provide quite a lot more information.